# Removing div opacity and applying pointer events in styles with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a div to lose its styling when any radio button has been selected.

Its current styling is:

```
#packages-and-payment{
    opacity: 0.4;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

I need the opacity to be removed and the pointer events to work again. I have been trying this in jQuery:

```
$(function() {

if ( $('input:radio:checked').length > 0 ) {
    $( '#packages-and-payment' ).css( "opacity", "0" );
    $( '#packages-and-payment' ).css( "pointer-events", "" );
}

});
```

But its not working?

What am I doing wrong or is there a better solution?

I need the opacity to be removed so becomes fully visible.

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/t9edq74u/

Comment: `Fiddle` your code with `markup`

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: When you say "opacity to be removed", do you mean it should be visible, or invisble? Because `opacity: 0` means invisible.

Comment: You've bound this behavior to document ready. Nothing different will happen when a radio button is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `opacity` to 0 will render the element completely invisible. If you want it to be visible you'll need to set the opacity to 1 instead:

```
$( '#packages-and-payment' ).css( "opacity", "1" );
```

Equally to reset the `pointer-events` property to its initial value, you'll need to set it to "auto" (in fact, setting it to "" is equivalent to setting it to `false`, which is interpreted as "none"):

```
$( '#packages-and-payment' ).css( "pointer-events", "auto" );
```

A much nicer way to set both at the same time is to pass an object into jQuery's `css()` method instead:

```
$( '#packages-and-payment' ).css({
    opacity: 1,
    pointerEvents: 'auto'
});
```

To trigger this to happen when a radio button is checked, you'll need to use an event handler:

```
$('input:radio').on('change', function() {
    if ($('input:radio:checked').length > 0)
        ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks this was perfect! I don't know who has been down voting all the answers, apologies. I found this v helpful, ta.

Answer (score 0):

By `.css("pointer-events", "");` you're restoring pointer-events as described in CSS (i.e. none), so better use `.css("pointer-events", "auto");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    if ( $('input:radio:checked').length > 0 ) {
        $( '#packages-and-payment' ).css( "opacity", "1" );
        $( '#packages-and-payment' ).css( "pointer-events", "auto" );
    }
});
```